# Get diff with GIT on windows

Tags: git

Using the git on windows, I don't see any option to compare two commits? I mean, how can I diff two revisions?
[image]

Comment: gitk works great even on Windows. If it's a small repo, one neat trick is to clone it twice and use Beyond Compare to diff the repo with its' copy, checked out from different commits.

Comment: Can you elaborate that? I didn't understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with git gui. Use gitk:

- start gitk from git gui via menu `Repository` -> `Visualize All Branch History`
- in gitk, click some commit and select `Mark this commit` from the context menu
- then select another commit and `Diff this -> marked commit`.

[image]